# Fill Nan based on group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to fill NaN based on a column values' mean.
Example:

```
       Groups      Temp

1        5          27
2        5          23
3        5          NaN  (will be replaced by 25)
4        1          NaN  (will be replaced by the mean of the Temps that are in group 1)
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `transfrom`, and lamdba function with `fillna` and `mean`:

```
df = df.assign(Temp=df.groupby('Groups')['Temp'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Temp
0  27.0
1  23.0
2  25.0
3   NaN
```

Comment: I will just delete my answer its the same anyway:)

Comment: I have other columns than the temp and groups, how can I precise to fillna only in temp ?